# Is there a xwindows freeware equivalent that is compatible with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, solaris, x-windows

The only thing I have at my disposal is xceed 6.0, but that is not compatible with Windows 7. And I am trying to connect this to a Solaris box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say to use [XMing](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/)

It's what we run at my work, replacing Exceed. It's a bit fiddly to get running (it's a Windows port of the UNIX xorg X Server, so it uses config files and command line flags a lot) but you should be able to get a config working and then use that one config for a while.

It also has an 'invisible' mode (-multiwindow) where X windows intermix with your MSWindows Windows. Pretty useful.